# PHP MySQLi (mysqli_result) Available Methods

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm wanting to implement a particular functionality in a MySQLi extension that I'm creating, but I don't want to do so if it's already there, or mostly there. I've thoroughly read over the documentation, and I'm just not sure if this or similar functionality is built-in; anyone know?

```
$db = new mysqli;

$sql = 'SELECT whatever...';
$obj = $db->fetchUpdate($sql);

// overwrite previous values
$obj->result['first'] = 'John';
$obj->result['last'] = 'Smith';

$obj->update(); // save to db
```

Again, I can put together a light wrapper extension that does this very thing; I just want to make sure it's not already part of the mysqli base methods and I've simply overlooked it in the documentation. Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not implemented in the MySQLi, that's why there's so many ORM's out there  :)

Comment: ORMs do many other things, too. This is more like ActiveRecord or such.